# Como criar uma classe com um NavigationDrawer para usar em várias Activities?

Tags: android, android-fragment, navigation-drawer

Comecei a estudar desenvolvimento Android a pouco tempo, vi que para usar um NavigationDrawer o recomendável é usar fragmentos para alterar um FrameLayout na Activity principal, porém nas novas activities que criar, não queria ter que colocar todo o código do NavigationDrawer novamente, queria saber como criar um menu para usar em qualquer uma.

Alguém tem alguma dica para me passar?

EDIT:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends GenericActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpDrawerLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**GenericActivity.java**

```
public class GenericActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    protected Toolbar toolbar;
    protected boolean drawerLayoutEnable;
    protected NavigationView navigationView;
    protected ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

    protected void setUpDrawerLayout(){
        this.drawerLayoutEnable = true;

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if(toolbar !=null){
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            setUpDrawerToggle();
            setUpNavigationView();
        }
    }

    private void setUpNavigationView() {
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener((NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) this);
    }

    private void setUpDrawerToggle(){
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, 
                drawerLayout, 
                toolbar, 
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_generic.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.rafael.elite.BaseActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout" //Seria este o drawer_layout que eu tenho que referenciar?
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:paddingTop="24dp"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_generic_activity" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa resposta do SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19451842/5165061

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, isso foi uma dúvida que eu me deparei quando decidi implementar o NavigationDrawer também no meu app, principalmente porque eu gostaria de ter activities em que eu utilizasse ele e outras activities que eu não utilizasse ele. E principalmente, não queria sair duplicando código pelas classes, então após pesquisar em diversos tutoriais eu adaptei e cheguei a esse resultado abaixo, de forma resumida porém você entenderá o conceito.

Criei uma GenericActivity onde todas as demais activities do meu aplicativo irão extendê-la:

```
public abstract class GenericActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    protected ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    protected NavigationView navigationView;
    protected NavigationViewMenuHandler navigationMenuHandler;
    //Com essa variável eu valido se a activity possui o NavigationDrawer
    //para realizar determinadas ações, ou não.
    protected boolean drawerLayoutEnable;

    //esse método é chamado pelas activities que extendem esta classe
    //e desejam ter um NavigationDrawer.
    protected void setUpDrawerLayout() {
        this.drawerLayoutEnable = true;

        //Toda a lógica de criação do NavigationDrawer vai neste método
        //Atualize com suas regras caso necessário
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_black_36dp);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            setUpDrawerToggle(); //configura o DrawerToggle
            setUpNavigationView(); //configura a NavigationView
        }
    }

    //Métodos private setUpDrawerToggle() e setUpNavigationView()
}
```

Agora todas activities do meu aplicativo que desejam ter o mesmo NavigationDrawer configurado extendem GenericActivity e apenas chamam o método `setUpDrawerLayout()` no `onCreate()`.

Por exemplo:

```
public class AppFootActivity extends GenericActivity {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.app_activity);
        //Chamo a configuração do NavigationDrawer. Caso eu não queira que
        //minha activity tenha um, basta não chamá-lo.
        setUpDrawerLayout();

        //Demais códigos da activity
    }

}
```

Esta mesma lógica pode ser aplicada em outros componentes como a ToolBar.

Levei em consideração que você já conhece como implementar o NavigationDrawer e tem apenas a dúvida de como fazê-lo em várias activities.

Abraço.

Comment: Julio, muito obrigado, estou seguindo sua resposta porém estou com um problema.
Quando tento rodar o app, recebo o seguinte erro:

 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.rafael.testenavigationdrawer/br.com.rafael.testenavigationdrawer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener)' on a null object reference

O erro acontece quando chamo o método SetupDrawerToggle() 
Editei a pergunta e coloquei meus arquivos

Comment: Pelo que eu pude perceber o seu drawerLayout está nulo no hora que ele vai chamar o método drawerLayout.toggle(). Você implementou o xml contendo o DrawerLayout? Note no código que ele chama findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout) tentando encontrar a view com este id.

Comment: Acho que estou implementando o correto, adicionei o xml da GenericActivity, se possível dá uma olhada e me diz o que acha.

Comment: Altera o seu xml deixando o DrawerLayout como view principal. Deixando <DrawerLayout> <AppBarLayout><Toolbar/></AppBarLayout> <NavigationView/> </DrawerLayout>.

Comment: Consegui, só esqueci de postar a resposta, o problema da NullPointerExcption era que eu tinha definido o drawer e a toolbar no arquivo xml da classe GenericActiviy, só depois percebi que ela não deve ter o arquivo e que a toolbar e o drawer devem ser definidos no xml da Activity que extende a classe GenericActivity. Agora a única questão, como fazer para que quando eu clicar no item do navigation drawer correspondente a activity em que eu estou, ela não seja recarregada mas somente feche o navigationDrawer?

Comment: Você pode criar uma outra pergunta no stack exemplificando melhor o seu caso, fica difícil ajudar pelos comentários. Porém, acredito que a resposta que você procura está nessa página: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: Já consegui a resposta, mesmo assim muito obrigado.