# Como adiconar só algumas Activity o navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Estou com uma dúvida de como posso adicionar o navigation drawer o menu lateral left, em algumas atividades. Comecei o projeto pelo BlakActivity e agora surgiu a necessidade de adicionar o menu lateral. Já tenho a `MainActivity`. Adiconada pelo proprio Android Studio.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Por exemplo essa Atividade preciso adiconar nela o menu Lateral segue o codigo:

```
public class DadosCadastraisActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{

    public EditText edtNome;
    private EditText edtCnpjCpf;
    private EditText edtRgIe;
    private EditText edtCep;
    private EditText edtUf;
    private EditText edtCidade;
    private EditText edtBairro;
    private EditText edtEndereco;
    private EditText edtnumero;
    private EditText edtComplemento;
    private EditText edtFoneComercial;
    private EditText edtFoneResidencial;
    private EditText edtFoneCelular;
    private EditText edtEmail;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private PessoaDao pessoaDao;
    private Pessoa pessoa;
    private LoginDao loginDao;
    private LoginSeralizable login;
    public Button btnEnviarDados;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dados_cadastrais);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        btnEnviarDados = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnviarDados);
        btnEnviarDados.setOnClickListener(this);


        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(DadosCadastraisActivity.this);



                try {


                    pessoaDao = new PessoaDao(databaseHelper.getConnectionSource());
                    pessoa = pessoaDao.queryForId(1);

                    edtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNome);
                    edtNome.setText(pessoa.getNome());

                    edtCnpjCpf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCnpjCpf);

                    if (pessoa.getCnpjCpf().length()==11){
                        edtCnpjCpf.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert(Mask.CPF_MASK, edtCnpjCpf));
                    }else {
                        edtCnpjCpf.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert(Mask.CNPJ_MASK, edtCnpjCpf));
                    }

                    edtCnpjCpf.setText(pessoa.getCnpjCpf());

                    edtRgIe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtRgIe);
                    edtRgIe.setText(pessoa.getRgIE());

                    edtCep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCEP);
                    edtCep.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert(Mask.CEP_MASK, edtCep));
                    edtCep.setText(pessoa.getCep());


                    edtUf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUF);
                    edtUf.setText(pessoa.getUf());

                    edtCidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCidade);
                    edtCidade.setText(pessoa.getCidade());

                    edtBairro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtBairro);
                    edtBairro.setText(pessoa.getBairro());

                    edtEndereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEndereco);
                    edtEndereco.setText(pessoa.getEndereco());

                    edtnumero = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNumero);
                    edtnumero.setText(pessoa.getNumero());

                    edtComplemento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtComplemento);
                    edtComplemento.setText(pessoa.getComplemento());

                    edtFoneComercial = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtFoneComercial);

                    if (pessoa.getFoneComercial().length()!=0){
                        edtFoneComercial.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert(Mask.TELEFONE_MASK, edtFoneComercial));
                    }

                    edtFoneComercial.setText(pessoa.getFoneComercial());

                    edtFoneResidencial = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtFoneResidencial);

                    if (pessoa.getFoneResidencial().length()!=0){
                        edtFoneResidencial.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert(Mask.TELEFONE_MASK, edtFoneResidencial));
                    }


                    edtFoneResidencial.setText(pessoa.getFoneResidencial());

                    edtFoneCelular = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtFoneCelular);
                    edtFoneCelular.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert(Mask.CELULAR_MASK,edtFoneCelular));
                    edtFoneCelular.setText(pessoa.getFoneCelular());

                    edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
                    edtEmail.setText(pessoa.getEmail());


                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

          new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {

                      DadosCadastraisActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                          public void run() {

                              try {
                                  loginDao = new LoginDao(databaseHelper.getConnectionSource());
                                  login = loginDao.queryForId(1);
                              } catch (SQLException e) {
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                              }


                              DadosCadastraisSerealizable dados = new DadosCadastraisSerealizable();


                              dados.codigo= String.valueOf(login.getCodigoCliente());
                              dados.usuario=login.usuario;
                              dados.senha=login.senha;

                              //expressão regular para enviar somente o numeros.


                              dados.cep= edtCep.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                              dados.bairro= edtBairro.getText().toString();

                              dados.endereco= edtEndereco.getText().toString();
                              dados.numero= edtnumero.getText().toString();
                              dados.complemento= edtComplemento.getText().toString();
                              dados.foneComercial= edtFoneComercial.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                              dados.foneResidencial= edtFoneResidencial.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                              dados.foneCelular= edtFoneCelular.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                              dados.email= edtEmail.getText().toString();

                              final WebService ws = new WebService();

                              try {
                                  ws.atuzalizarCadastroCliente(dados);
                              } catch (IOException e) {
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                              } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                              }

                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ws.strFault, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                      });




              }

          }).start();



    }


    }
```

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta! Você te uma Activity e que adicionar o menu lateral nela?

Comment: Quero que quase todas minhas activity tenha o menu lateral nela, @ThiagoLuizDomacoski

Comment: Então, as que terão o Menu Lateral, na verdade serão [Fragment's](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer), e as que não tem, serão Activity's normais!

Comment: No caso essas Activitys já estão criadas, é só mudar para Fragment's? @ThiagoLuizDomacoski

Comment: Não entendo o seu problema já que, normalmente, o problema está em adicionar um navigation drawer, ou [ter todas as Activities com ele, sem repetir código](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103964/2541)

Comment: Olha o link que o @ramaral comentou! Serve perfeitamente para o seu caso!

Comment: Vou olhar, mas editei  a pergunta tbm, se puder dar mais uma olhada por favor, @ThiagoLuizDomacoski

Comment: @rodrigo.oliveira o nav drawer é "preso" sempre a uma activity, então se você quer ele em várias "telas" do seu programa, vc precisa usar a estratégia de fragments, só trocando o conteúdo de uma activity central que coordena tudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se trabalha com activities e quer o drawer em algumas, deve colocar os códigos, do `XML` e o Java:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

              DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

só nas que deseja. Então ele irá aparecer somente nessas.

EDIT:

XML Main:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

..........................
..........................

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

XML Outra Activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

..........................
..........................

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Codigo Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Intent intent;
    private MapController mapController;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //codigo da main
}
```

Outra activity deve ter estes mesmos códigos implementados.
Ex.:

```
public class RotaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rota);

        //Incluindo a toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
//mesmo codigo da main
}
```

Comment: Usando dessa forma deu esse erro:


This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: implementou o navigation, assim como na main?
`implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Comment: sim, implemetei, quando eu adicionei esse código o android studio mesmo já pediu para implementar.

Comment: Seu XML de layout desta activity não está no post, mas acredito que ele tenha de vir com o :

`<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`

Esta tag do drawer sobre tudo, provavelmente como está no XML da main

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta com um exemplo